# Lightweight browser for low bandwidth internet (64 kbit/s)

Tags: windows, android, web-browser, connection-speed

Looking for something like a lightweight browser, for Windows and or Android, that don't interrupt site loading and if possible save whole pages, like .pdf.

Talking about a browser/plugin what loads only text and images, videos and scripts can be toggle on and off, and can still have a decent layout so that u can read prob.

But the first point, so that it don't interrupt loading and I can just wait, would be good.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered Lynx?

It's text only, but very usable.

It's available for most platforms. It's open-source. Visit their site here: https://lynx.invisible-island.net/release/

If you're using a Mac, start a Terminal and execute "brew install lynx".
For Windows, visit [the Lynx installer page](https://invisible-island.net/lynx/#installers)